# Convert string with unicode characters e.g. →,∧,¬ into strings illustrated in latex?

Tags: python, latex, converters, tex

Is their a way or method in python which is able to convert strings in which logical symbols occur as unicode characters into latex code:

means:

```
str1 = '¬q→ ¬p→q'
```

into

```
str1_tex = '$\neg q\rightarrow \neg p\rightharrow q'
```

or

```
str2 = 'q∧ q'
```

into

```
str2_tex = '$q \wedge q$'
```

Comment: make a map with a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could safe yourself the hassle to convert your strings if you compile with an unicode-aware engine like lualatex or xelatex:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\[
¬q→ ¬p→q
\]

\[
\neg q\rightarrow \neg p\rightarrow q
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is possible. Check out the following repo: https://github.com/mennucc/unicode2latex

Optionally you can define everything yourself by using a dictionary.