# How to write unicode characters to LaTeX document via pylatex

Tags: python, character-encoding, latex, pdflatex, pylatex

Assume the string `myStr` which contains three special characters.

```
myStr = "emdash —; delta Δ; thin space:  ;"
```

Further assume that we wish to write this string to a LaTeX document via [pylatex](https://pypi.org/project/PyLaTeX/).

If we write the string as is to a LaTeX document, errors occur during its compilation:

```
import pylatex
doc = pylatex.Document()
with doc.create(pylatex.Section('myStr -- not encoded')):
    doc.append(myStr)
doc.generate_pdf("myStr_notEncoded", clean_tex=False)

...
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Δ (U+0394)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
...
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character   (U+2009)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
...
```

If we first encode the string via [pylatexenc](https://pypi.org/project/pylatexenc/), the special characters are either represented by their respective LaTeX encoding (emdash, delta) or encoded in a way unclear to me (thin space).

```
import pylatexenc
from pylatexenc import latexencode
myStr_latex = pylatexenc.latexencode.unicode_to_latex(myStr)
doc = pylatex.Document()
with doc.create(pylatex.Section('myStr')):
    doc.append(myStr_latex)
doc.generate_pdf("myStr", clean_tex=False)
```

[image]

How do I have to write the string into the LaTeX document so that the special characters are printed as the actual characters when compiling with pdflatex?

**Edit 1:**

I also tried to change the default encoding inside the LaTeX document for the unencoded pathway but it results in a series of compilation errors as well.

```
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape("\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}"))
```

Comment: Can you switch to an unicode aware engine like xelatex or lualatex?

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72764353/convert-string-with-unicode-characters-e-g-%e2%86%92-%e2%88%a7-%c2%ac-into-strings-illustrated-in-la/72764691#72764691

Comment: I can't switch to another TeX engine, as this is part of a larger pipeline. It has to be pdflatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your [`pylatexenc`](https://pypi.org/project/pylatexenc/) solution. When you encode latex yourself, e.g. with [`pylatexenc.latexencode.unicode_to_latex()`](https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/latexencode/#pylatexenc.latexencode.unicode_to_latex) you have to ensure that you tell pylatex the string should not be additional escaped. [To wit](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/usage.html#unescaping-strings):

> Using regular LaTeX strings may not be as simple as is seems though, because by default almost all strings are escaped[...] there are cases where raw LaTeX strings should just be used directly in the document. This is why the `NoEscape`string type exists. This is just a subclass of `str`, but it will not be escaped

In other words to solve, just make sure to use `NoEscape` to tell pylatex your string is already encoded as latex and not to encode it again:

```
import pylatex
from pylatexenc import latexencode
myStr_latex = latexencode.unicode_to_latex(myStr)
doc = pylatex.Document()
with doc.create(pylatex.Section('myStr')):
    doc.append(pylatex.utils.NoEscape(myStr_latex))
doc.generate_pdf("myStr", clean_tex=False)
```

[image: The generated pdf, properly encoded (emdash —; delta ∆; thin space: ;)]

Comment: Thanks for this succinct answer! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Until a better solution has been found, a workable (although by no means preferable) solution would be to encode all the offending characters via the package `newunicodechar`:

```
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.Command('usepackage', 'newunicodechar'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{²}{\ensuremath{{}^2}}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{ }{\,}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r"\newunicodechar{′}{'}"))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{−}{\ensuremath{-}}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{∶}{\ensuremath{:}}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{≤}{\ensuremath{\leq}}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{≥}{\ensuremath{\geq}}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{α}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{β}{\ensuremath{\beta}}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{Δ}{\ensuremath{\Delta}}')) ## (U+0394)
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{∆}{\ensuremath{\Delta}}')) ## (U+2206)
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{λ}{\ensuremath{\lambda}}'))
doc.preamble.append(pylatex.NoEscape(r'\newunicodechar{μ}{\ensuremath{\mu}}'))
```